# Excel workbook closed through vba code still running in the process

Tags: ms-access, vba

Through Access VBA i'm opening the workbook and make visible=False, and then i do something and closing. But it is still running in the **Taskmanager**.

```
     Dim ExcelApp As New Excel.Application
     Dim ExcelBook As New Excel.Workbook
     Dim rng As Excel.Range
     Dim rngDefine As Excel.Range

     Set ExcelBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("C\temp\find.xlsm")
     ExcelApp.Visible = False       

     '//Do something

    ExcelApp.Quit
    ExcelBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Set ExcelBook = Nothing
    Set ExcelApp = Nothing
```

Comment: I'd close the workbook before quitting Excel.

Answer (score 2):

The commenters above are correct, your new workbook isn't associated with your `ExcelApp` instance.  So at the end you're closing your new `ExcelApp` instance and closing the new workbook you created, but I think the new workbook is opening in a new instance of Excel... maybe, so you'd still see an orphaned Excel process in the task manager.  I'd change your code to something more like this:

```
Dim ExcelApp as Excel.Application
Dim ExcelBook as Excel.Workbook
Dim rng As Excel.Range
Dim rngDefine As Excel.Range
Set ExcelApp = New Excel.Application
Set ExcelBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("C\temp\find.xlsm")
'ExcelApp.Visible = False   You could maybe comment this out unless you use ".Activate" somewhere.  It should be the default anyway.
...
'At the end:
ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
ExcelBook.Close
ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = True
ExcelApp.Quit
'If right before "End Sub" the next two lines are of arguable necesity, but likely good practice
Set ExcelBook = Nothing
Set ExcelApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Having run into this headache very recently too, I'd comment that if you use an unqualified Range or Worksheet or Workbook even once it can keep the process open.  Every single command on the workbook should reference fully -     excelapp.excelbook.excelsheet.range("A1")  I went crazy the other day with this until I realized my .Find function included an unqualified "Range" in its arguments

Comment: @Acantud I feel like I'm being overly strict doing it sometimes, but I started diming and setting everything to objects due to odd "OLE automation errors" that I kept getting.  Having everything completely locked down seemed to avoid that as well.